# variable inheritance in VC form app

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I need some help with variable inheritance in VC form app! I have this code:

```
string ks;          
ifstream sfile(ks);

if (sfile)
{
    PatInfo ^ form = gcnew PatInfo;
    form->ShowDialog();

}                                           
else 
{
    MessageBox::Show( "Please try again.");
}
```

I want to pass the ks string to PatInfo form. How can it be done?

Comment: You need to create a constructor parameter.

Comment: A form is just a class.  Which lets you modify the constructor so you can pass a value.  Or you can add a public property which you then can assign and read back.  Very basic programming techniques, be sure to read your C++/CLI languge book for guidance.